# System frozen and lightdm does not restart

Tags: xorg, lightdm

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS on an Intel Core i7-3770.

After running a test program I wrote myself, that was allocating all the memory, just to see how long it would take it to run out of memory, the system returned right (except for a minor thing that will be the subject of a separate question) and started running almost normally: just a little slow. I didn't think it would be a big deal until a few minutes later it just froze. The mouse doesn't move, the keyboard is dead, I can't log in to another console with `ctrl+alt+Fx`; nothing. I can ssh into it from my laptop though, and that's what I did.

I don't know if this freezing could be related to my program that just used up all the memory, including the swap, thereby receiving an exception, which in turn terminated the program and returned the memory to the system.

At any rate what I tried so far is:

`sudo service lightdm restart`

nothing. It hangs forever until I just have to `ctrl+c` it.

I found the PID of X, killed it and tried to restart it with

`startx &`

it tried to connect forever (I don't know how long because I went eating in the meantime) and then it said:

> xinit: giving up
>
> xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
>
> waiting for X server to shut down ..........
>
> xinit: X server slow to shut down, sending KILL signal
>
> waiting for server to die ...
>
> xinit: X server refuses to die

and it didn't even return the control to the console. It is listed as `<defunct>` in `ps`.

I can send sysrq signals, but before I send it a `b` I would like to know if there is anything else I could try.

After checking some more, I found out that `ps` does indeed list `Xorg.wrap` as the dreaded `D<`, meaning it's uninterruptible. I have read elsewhere that the only thing that helps in such a case is a reboot. If anyone knows any better, please shed some light.